# Problem with getting an environmental variable through os.getenv()

Tags: python, environment-variables

I'm trying to code a discord bot, so, to avoid showing the token directly in the code, I'm going for an environmental variable.

In my `TOKEN.env` file, I wrote `TOKEN=*token*`, and this is my code, but Python won't get the variable.

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I'm using pycharm and Python 3.9

Comment: The default filename is `.env`, not `TOKEN.env`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are saving your environment variables in `TOKEN.env`, you need to tell `dotenv` to use this file:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('path/to/file/TOKEN.env')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option #1:** Default path

Save the config in a file called `.env`.

Then, use this code in your application:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```

**Option #2:** Use a custom path

Just load from any path:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('path/to/file/TOKEN.env')
```

**Option #3:** Set the environment variable while running the app

You don't need to do anything from inside your Python code except for calling `os.getenv`.

You do however need to run your application while specifying the value:

```
>> TOKEN=*token* python3 script.py
- OR -
>> TOKEN=*token* ./script.py
```